# Futher optimization of Postgres Full-text search on a Cloud Server

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, cloud, postgresql-performance

I am running Postgres 9.1 on a cloud server (which I'm aware is far from ideal, we are hoping to migrate at some point this year). This server frequently performs full text queries on a table with more than 3 million records. Here is an example of a typical query.

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table 
WHERE datepublished BETWEEN $$2012-05-01 00:00:00$$ AND $$2013-05-15 23:59:59$$ 
  AND hide = false 
  AND ( tsvall @@ to_tsquery('query')) 
ORDER BY datepublished DESC
```

The columns datepublished, hide and tsvall are all indexed , tsvall is indexed using GIN. The postgres configuration settings shared_buffers, effective_cache_size, work_mem have also been tweaked.

For an a typical query (query text used was "august") using the parameters in the example above returning 986 rows took 5 seconds. I really would like to get to speed this up. Your help would be greatly appreciated, I can provide extra information on request.

--EDIT : EXPLAIN ANALYSE RESULTS

```
 Sort  (cost=15352.87..15355.18 rows=927 width=16) (actual time=17705.293..17706.266 rows=849 loops=1)
   Sort Key: datepublished
   Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 64kB
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on post  (cost=1049.44..15307.18 rows=927 width=16) (actual time=63.520..17702.219 rows=849 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (tsvall @@ to_tsquery('trialing'::text))
         Filter: ((at IS NULL) AND (NOT hide) AND (datepublished >= '2012-05-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datepublished <= '2013-06-04 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tsvall  (cost=0.00..1049.20 rows=3758 width=0) (actual time=62.537..62.537 rows=4814 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (tsvall @@ to_tsquery('trialing'::text))
 Total runtime: 17707.280 ms
```

here is a link as requested in the comments http://explain.depesz.com/s/QDAb

--EDIT 2

I realised that my datepublished index was not orderd so I have created a (btree) index on the column which is ordered DESC. Here is an example of an EXPLAIN ANALYSE output I am now getting

```
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on post  (cost=65485.44..82297.13 rows=4441 width=16) (actual time=1397.734..7775.204 rows=3161 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((tsvall @@ to_tsquery('debate'::text)) AND (datepublished >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datepublished <= '2013-06-04 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone) AND (at IS NULL))
         Filter: (NOT hide)
         ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=65485.44..65485.44 rows=4456 width=0) (actual time=1396.544..1396.544 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tsvall  (cost=0.00..13526.88 rows=67979 width=0) (actual time=531.941..531.941 rows=71502 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (tsvall @@ to_tsquery('debate'::text))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on datepublished_index  (cost=0.00..23142.92 rows=1103417 width=0) (actual time=382.808..382.808 rows=1164707 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((datepublished >= '2013-04-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datepublished <= '2013-06-04 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_at  (cost=0.00..28811.80 rows=1253179 width=0) (actual time=422.077..422.077 rows=1319617 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (at IS NULL)
```

And here again is the link as requested http://explain.depesz.com/s/Ksss

Mark

Comment: Run `analyze table`, followed by `explain analyze this-query`. Paste the results into your question.

Comment: ... and remember to code-indent explain analyze; the formatting is important. Best is to paste to http://explain.depesz.com/ and link here. Use `explain (buffers, analyze) ... ` if your server version supports it. See the info tab on [tag:postgresql-performance].

Comment: @CraigRinger I have added them - sorry for the long delay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statistics estimates are reasonable, and it's a pretty simple query plan. That in its self is part of the problem.

The (very) expensive node is the bitmap heap scan:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on post (cost=1049.44..15307.18 rows=927 width=16) (actual time=63.520..17702.219 rows=849 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (tsvall @@ to_tsquery('trialing'::text))
  Filter: ((at IS NULL) AND (NOT hide) AND (datepublished >= '2012-05-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datepublished <= '2013-06-04 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
```

See the big, complex filter clause? That's a bit odd, in that it means Pg isn't using any other indexes to satisfy these conditions.

Does reducing your `random_page_cost` cause Pg to use any other indexes?

In a worst case, you might be able to use an explicit CTE to force Pg to do the other filters first, then apply the tsquery on the result. This would require a bit materialize, so it's not ideal, something like:

```
WITH prefiltered AS (
  SELECT id, tsvall, datepublished
  FROM Table 
  WHERE datepublished BETWEEN '2012-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-05-15 23:59:59' 
    AND hide = false 
)
SELECT
FROM prefiltered
WHERE tsvall @@ to_tsquery('query')
ORDER BY datepublished DESC;
```

Alternately, as Denis so sensibly pointed out, try creating a composite btree-gist index like:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_blah ON posts USING gist(datepublished, tsvall) WHERE (hide = false);
```

... though the greater size of this index and its update cost may be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for analysing that, is the fact that Postgre is running on a cloud server significant to random_page_cost?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are it's ignoring the index on tsvall because it's less selective than the one on datepublished.

If so, try adding a GIN or GIST index on `(tsvall, datepublished)`.

You might need to install the btree_gin or btree_gist extension as appropriate:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/btree-gin.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/btree-gist.html

Make sure to `analyze` your table afterwards.

Comment: I currently use a GIN index on tsvall. I saw a performance decrease when adding a btree_gin(tsvall,datepublished) index . I did however see an increase in search performance with a btree_gist index(tsvall,datepublished) - which I don't understand as generally I know GIN indexes have faster read times. Could it be to do with the number of lexemes for each index entry? Tsvall certainly has over 100 000 unique lexemes in total.These tests however were only on my development laptop and not on our production server